# Trying to edit Agenda tab in Events gives a DB error

Tags: civievent, error, database

CiviCRM 5.50.1, WordPress 6.0.1, 8.0.28.

Someone recently tried to add an Agenda to an Event in CiviCRM, and kept getting a network error. I took a look, and yeah, going to the Agenda tab seems to cause a crash. The log file shows lots of stuff, but this:

[nativecode=1055 ** Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'civicrm_members.esspeaker.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by]

seems to be the most useful entry. I've seen this type of error in other posts, but nothing for the event Agenda. Most of the hits I find suggest these should have been fixed by now, so, is this a bug in CiviCRM? Not seeing anything that looks like a bug fix note in newer versions.

I'm hesitant to reconfigure SQL to turn off only_full_group_by as a workaround unless that's the only way around this (and honestly, there was no need for an Agenda, as that seems to be a bit more than a text note anyway based on the fact that it cares so much about the database).

Any other ideas / fixes? I'll probably upgrade the system tomorrow as it looks like 5.51.1 may fix another bug we've hit (automatic renewal during contribution) and will update this note if I get the update done and it resolves the issue.

Thanks.

Michael

Answer (score 0):

The `esspeaker` part is coming from the civimobile extension: https://civicrm.org/extensions/civimobileapi

Might want to file an issue there if it's not already fixed in a recent version: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civimobileapi

Comment: Ah. Hadn't thought of that, thanks. Extensions (minus Payment Shared) are all up to date.